# How to login in with Curl and cookies

Tags: authentication, curl, web-scraping, php-curl

I am trying to login to apollohousewares.co.uk website using curl. I want to retrieve the the price information after logging. I am new to curl so need help. When i am posting the data it is showing invalid username and password but same credentials are working when login using browser.

```
//username and password of account
$username = trim(' ');
$password = trim(' ');

//login form action url ///

$url="https://apollohousewares.co.uk/members/login/"; 

$postinfo = "username=".urlencode($username)."&password=".urlencode($password);

$cookie_file_path = "cookie.txt";

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "cookiename=0"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postinfo);
curl_exec($ch);

//page with the content I want to grab
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://apollohousewares.co.uk/members/customers/target/home/");

echo $html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

also, my cookie.txt is writable and working

Answer (score 1):

Open the site in browser and locate the URL that is hit when login button is clicked in "Network" tab of "Developer Tools" window.
Right click on the row and select "Copy as cURL"
That will be your complete curl command with all arguments and post body.
This way you can see how username and password in encoded.